# How to use JWT token issued by authentication server to allow access to another app?

Tags: oauth-2.0, vuejs2, jwt

I have app A ( Java API backend) as authentication server based on username and password. After successful login, the authentication server returns below JSON response:

> {"access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOlsiYWNjb3VudC1yZXNvdXJjZSJdLCJ1c2VyX25hbWUiOiJzZWNvbmRfbGV2ZWxfbWFuYWdlckBjb21wYW55LmNvbSIsInNjb3BlIjpbInJlYWQiLCJ3cml0ZSJdLCJleHAiOjE1MzMwMTk1ODksImF1dGhvcml0aWVzIjpbIlNFQ09ORF9MRVZFTF9NQU5BR0VSIl0sImp0aSI6ImZiYWJjZDM3LTc3OTEtNGU5YS1hNDg3LTU1YjI5ZDJhMDZhMiIsImNsaWVudF9pZCI6ImNybS1mcm9udGVuZCJ9.CdIe1xtDJhgk5px3uIfAS9cvabMNox9Pa7KUEc5qka4","token_type":"bearer","refresh_token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOlsiYWNjb3VudC1yZXNvdXJjZSJdLCJ1c2VyX25hbWUiOiJzZWNvbmRfbGV2ZWxfbWFuYWdlckBjb21wYW55LmNvbSIsInNjb3BlIjpbInJlYWQiLCJ3cml0ZSJdLCJhdGkiOiJmYmFiY2QzNy03NzkxLTRlOWEtYTQ4Ny01NWIyOWQyYTA2YTIiLCJleHAiOjE1MzM2MjA3ODksImF1dGhvcml0aWVzIjpbIlNFQ09ORF9MRVZFTF9NQU5BR0VSIl0sImp0aSI6IjM5OTAwNDZjLThmOWMtNDMzNi1hOTlmLTFiMjIzZjAyMjcwNyIsImNsaWVudF9pZCI6ImNybS1mcm9udGVuZCJ9.V8cn5x7OefgJUwF68abxHCF8cB0axZf1edRGGnd4wkY","expires_in":3599,"scope":"read
>   write","jti":"fbabcd37-7791-4e9a-a487-55b29d2a06a2"}

The login form is in VueJS frontend app B. After successful login, the user is authorized to access protected resources (lets say view Bar objects, perform CRUD operations on Bar objects). The backend API for these Bar objects is another app C which is NodeJS app. So app A and app C backends running on separate servers and ports.

How can I protect (ie. allow only successfully logged in user) to accesss and manipulate Bar objects using above access_token and jti and expiration?

One way is to check for expiration time before allowing access to protected resources  each time protected resource URL endpoints are touched. But is this correct approach and hack proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the authentication header from the incoming message and base64 decode the first half of the JWT to get your user details and the expiry.  I've done that using jwt.io and you get

```
{
  "aud": [
    "account-resource"
  ],
  "user_name": "second_level_manager@company.com",
  "scope": [
    "read",
    "write"
  ],
  "exp": 1533019589,
  "authorities": [
    "SECOND_LEVEL_MANAGER"
  ],
  "jti": "fbabcd37-7791-4e9a-a487-55b29d2a06a2",
  "client_id": "crm-frontend"
}
```

But to trust that this hasn't been tampered with you need to check the signature.  I normally use passport with node https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-jwt

You probably defined the 256 bit secret when you encoded the JWT to begin with

Checking the signature makes sure the the base64 encoded part which is not securely encoded has not been altered.

Comment: thank u for valuable info. But I did not get the verification part to make sure it is not altered. On server side it uses client_id and client_secret which 16 alphnumeric chars string which is also used in browser side to send in the basic auth header when login along with userid and user password. Is there a library that I just use in browser to check signature (not paid service like auth0.com ?

Comment: are the "16 alphnumeric chars" the secret you used to sign the jwt? Which library are you using in java?  I think the package most people are using to verify in node (and the one listed on jwt.io) is https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken but you will need the secret to decode.

Comment: client_secret is not the signing key, on server side it uses spring security jwt library to encode the jwt token and sign it with 32 chars signing key. I am still confused if I use this secret signing key in browser js code to verify JWT token then I am exposing this signing key to end user.

Comment: Definitely don't put the secret in the client side code.  You should put all your controls on the API side not the client side.  You can use the information on the client side to inform which API to use but if there were an attack where the jwt was modified the API could give a unauthorised response.